# ¿Cómo guardar Array de Schema.Types.ObjectId y obtener sus ID? Mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mi intención en el proyecto que estoy realizando es que el usuario cree una publicación que contenga Titulo, Descripción, IMG y `Secciones` donde Secciones es un `Array` que almacena los `Schema.Types.ObjectId` de los datos guardados en el Schema Secciones. Las secciones el Usuario es quien las va añadiendo con un botón.

Cada sección debe ser independiente, deben contar con su propio ID porque me gustaría implementar una zona de comentarios para cada sección. Todas las secciones deben guardarse junto a la publicación general cuando se le de al botón publicar.

**Problématica:**

Lo que me percaté es que para poder crear una publicación, antes debo guardar la DATA de Seccion del `req.body` en el `Schema Secciones` para obtener sus ID y así poder pasarselos a la `variable` que cuenta con el `Schema Publicaciones`.

No se como guardar las Secciones de manera individual y obtener sus ID y luego pasar la DATA al Schema Publicaciones. Intenté recorrer el `array` y que en la posición `[i]` se hiciera un `save()` pero no me funcionó, se va directo al `CATCH`.

**Schema Publicaciones:**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const PublicacionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        titulo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        grado: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        materia: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        submateria: [{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }],
        seccion: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Secciones', 
            default: []
        }],
        autor: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Usuario', 
            default: []
        }],
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    },
    {
        collection: 'publicaciones'
    }
);

PublicacionSchema.method('toJSON', function(){
    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});


module.exports = model('Publicaciones', PublicacionSchema);
```

**Schema Secciones:**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const SeccionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        titulo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    },
    {
        collection: 'secciones'
    }
);

SeccionSchema.method('toJSON', function(){
    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});


module.exports = model('Secciones', SeccionSchema);
```

**Schema Usuario:**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const UsuarioSchema = new Schema(
    {
        nombre: {
            type: String,
            required: true // El campo es obligatorio
        },
        nickname: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
            trim: true, // Los espacios serán eliminados
            unique: true // El elemento debe ser unico y no repetirse
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        materias: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Materia', 
            default: []
        }],
        estado: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: 'USER_ROLE'
        },
        verificado: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
        google: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true //Guardar la fecha de creación y de actualización
    }
);

UsuarioSchema.method('toJSON', function(){
    const { __v, _id, password, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});


module.exports = model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

**Controllers Publicaciones:**

```
const { response } = require('express');
const PublicacionModel = require('../models/publicacion');
const SeccionModel = require('../models/secciones');


const controller = {
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    //<!-- Inicio Crear Publicación -->
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    crearPublicacion: async(req, res = response) => {

        // DATA de USUARIO - DATA de PUBLICACIÓN
        const uid = req.id;
        const publicacion = new PublicacionModel({
            autor: uid,
            ...req.body
        });


        try {
            const newSeccion = new SeccionModel(req.body.seccion);

            for (let i = 0; i < newSeccion.length; i++) {
                newSeccion.save();
            }

            const publicacionDB = new PublicacionModel({
                publicacion,
                newSeccion
            });


            // Guardar publicación
            await publicacionDB.save();


            // Respuesta
            res.json({
                ok: true,
                publicacion: publicacionDB,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: 'Error inesperado.... revisar logs'
            });
        }
    },
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
    //<!-- Fin Crear Publicación -->
    //<!-- ============================================================== -->
}



module.exports = controller;
```

**Datos Mandado por PostMan:**

```
{
    "titulo": "Mi primera publicación",
    "descripcion": "Esto es un tema muy extenso.",
    "grado": "Primaria",
    "materia": "Español",
    "submateria": ["Arte", "Español"],
    "seccion": [
        {
            "titulo": "Paso 1",
            "descripcion": "Esto debe tomarse con mucha seriedad."
        },
        {
            "titulo": "Paso 2",
            "descripcion": "Esto debe tomarse con mucha seriedad."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No es necesario esperar a que el campo `_id` sea generado por el motor de base de datos. De hecho, lo aconsejable es que realices la operación de forma atómica en una sola transacción. De esta forma te aseguras que tus datos sean consistentes. En cuanto pueda, y si no te han dado aún una respuesta, dejaré una. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Por lo que me dices, entonces es extraer la Data de las secciones, pasarlas directo al Schema Publicaciones y hacer el Save.

Comment: Puedes obtener los objetos a salvar y usar `insertMany` de Mongoose sobre cada modelo. Lo ideal, usando un objeto de sesión. Puedes leer [transacciones en Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html). Las transacciones son algo relativamente nuevo en MongoDB.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias a tu respuesta logré guardar de manera individual mis Secciones en el Modelo Secciones, ya cuentan con sus ID. Utilicé el inserMany como indicaste pero, ahora el resto de los datos de la Publicación, no logro guardarlos. Ya intenté crear un insertMany para cada Modelo (Publicación y Secciones) pero de momento el de Secciones es el unico que guarda la información (Lo tengo antes del de publicaciones). Utilicé el SAVE en Publicaciones y tampoco. No sé si se pueda anidar los insertMany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Gracias a la información que me proporcionó **Mauricio Contreras** logré implementar el Guardar datos de un `Schema` Principal (En mi caso Publicaciones) al mismo tiempo que guardo los datos de otro `Schema` (En mi caso Secciones) que sus ID están referenciados y guardados en un Array en mi Schema Principal.

Para lograr esto es necesario recurrir al método `insertMany` que nos proporciona `Moongose` el cual es un atajo para validar una serie de documentos e insertarlos en MongoDB si todos son válidos. [para saber más sobre inserMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-insertMany).

La sintaxis es sencilla. Debemos seleccionar el modelo de nuestra `Collection`, llamar al `insertMany`, pasarle los Datos y usar el `then` y `catch` para capturar errores y obtener una respuesta.

**Ejemplo siguiendo la teoría:**

```js
const { response } = require('express');
const PublicacionModel = require('../models/publicacion'); // Modelo Publicación

const controller = {
  crearPublicacion: async(req, res = response) => {
  
    PublicacionModel.insertMany(req.body)
    .then((data) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            data
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: error
        });
    });
    
  }
}

module.exports = controller;
```

Pero para conseguir mi resultado tuve que hacer dos `insertMany`, primero para guardar los datos de mi `campo seccion` y el segundo para guardar los datos general de lo que es publicaciones.

Algo que hay que considerar es que en una `función` sólo podemos tener una `respuesta`, así que por esa razón se omite el `response` del primer `insertMany` y lo dejamos simplemente en `return`.

**Ejemplo completo de mi solución:**

```js
const { response } = require('express');
const PublicacionModel = require('../models/publicacion'); // Modelo Publicación
const SeccionModel = require('../models/secciones'); // Modelo Sección

const controller = {
  crearPublicacion: async(req, res = response) => {
  
    try {
        // insertMany para Secciones de la publicación
        const seccionDB = await SeccionModel.insertMany(req.body.seccion)
        .then((secciones) => {
            return secciones;
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: error
            });
        });
        
        // insertMany para los datos completos de la publicación
        await PublicacionModel.insertMany([{
            autor: req.id,
            seccion: seccionDB,
            titulo: req.body.titulo,
            descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
            grado: req.body.grado,
            materia: req.body.materia,
            submateria: req.body.submateria,
        }])
        .then((publicaciones) => {
            res.status(200).json({
                ok: true,
                publicaciones
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: error
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'Error inesperado.... revisar logs'
        });
    }
    
  }
}

module.exports = controller;
```